# Google Chart(Pie Chart) Bug?

Tags: google-visualization

Please check the following chart and why the size of 10.52% and 2.72 are the same?

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=pc&chxs=0,000000,9&chxt=x&chs=490x200&chp=4.7&chd=t:720,207,322,108,69,283,519,246,138,158,89,344&chl=%2822.03%25%29|%286.33%25%29|%289.85%25%29|%283.30%25%29|%282.11%25%29|%288.65%25%29|%2815.88%25%29|%287.52%25%29|%284.22%25%29|%284.83%25%29|%282.72%25%29|%2810.52%25%29&chco=FF00FF|336699|800000|FF00FF|ff6600|808000|0099cc|3366ff|000000|3399ff|C0C0C0|800080|00FF00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chd=t: values are percentage. I thought they were values and google chart will work out the percentage for them.

It has been fixed as soon as I replaced actual values with percentage values. The chart is fixed.

Comment: Glad you found the answer, but it might be worth looking at the new API for charts as the pie chart will now take values and work out the percentages for you: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Comment: Thanks but I am putting that chart on PDF to generate the report and only image can be put on PDF document. I would really LOVE to use the new pie chart design. Do you have any idea to put these codes "<svg>
<defs id="defs">
<rect>
<g>
<text>My Daily Activities</text>
</g><g>
<path >
<text text-anchor="start" x="438.1707648577682" y="240.34252366466197" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">45.8%</text>
</g>
</svg>" on PDF generator? Or is there anyway we can convert them to image? I am using "itextsharp.dll" to generate the PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

You were just missing the `chds=a` parameter, which specifies "automatic scaling" of the values. Add that and the chart will be correct when the data are not percentages.

See: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats#textformatautoscaling

Here is [your example chart with the added parameter](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=pc&chxs=0,000000,9&chxt=x&chs=490x200&chp=4.7&chd=t:720,207,322,108,69,283,519,246,138,158,89,344&chl=%2822.03%25%29|%286.33%25%29|%289.85%25%29|%283.30%25%29|%282.11%25%29|%288.65%25%29|%2815.88%25%29|%287.52%25%29|%284.22%25%29|%284.83%25%29|%282.72%25%29|%2810.52%25%29&chco=FF00FF|336699|800000|FF00FF|ff6600|808000|0099cc|3366ff|000000|3399ff|C0C0C0|800080|00FF00&chds=a).

Unfortunately you'll get seemingly-accurate results without this parameter a lot of the time, so it's easy to miss it. It appears to me that it's basically a requirement for pie charts, though, so I can't imagine why it isn't the default behaviour.

Providing exact percentage values might also work correctly in all situations. I don't actually know the details of the problem, only that automatic scaling solves it when it occurs, so I'm inclined to suggest using it just in case.